# i am getting a null response from a webservice but i want to compare that null value

Tags: json, null, response

```
let send: String = String(format:"http://abc.xyz/%@",userName)
    print(send)
    let url=URL(string:send)
    do
    {
        let userData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let loginResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: userData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [string:Anyobject]
        print(loginResponse)
        let arr=(loginResponse["Activities"])
        if (![loginResponse["Activities"]]=NSNull)
        {
            print(arr!)

        }
```

**if the response is not null then i need to add some objects to arrays**